# How would I skip spaces in a foreach loop?

Tags: c#, string, foreach

C# newbie here.

I am using a foreach statement to loop through a string of characters and write numerical values to an **int** based on their position in the alphabet.

This is working correctly but it throws this error when I attempt to skip spaces in the string:

> Cannot assign to "c" because it is a foreach iteration variable.

Here is my code:

```
foreach (char c in encodedText)
{
    if (c = " ");
    {
        continue;
    }

    int index = char.ToUpper(c) - 64;
    Console.WriteLine(index);
}
```

Comment: Use `==` for comparisons. `=` indicates assignment.

Comment: Two things, you are trying to compare a char, which uses `'single quotes'`, unlike strings. Also, in C#, the comparison operator is `==`. The `=` operator is an assignment operator, so the compiler thinks you are trying to assign a vlue to `c`, not compare it.

Comment: Daniel and Glorin already pointed out that a single `=` is used to assign a value to a variable, whereas 2 (`==`) is used to compare two values. I just wanted to add that this is different than VB however, where 1 is used for both. Perhaps you're coming from VB and were confused, or just made a minor type-o and forgot the second one? I know it was tagged as C#, but since they're both .NET I just figured I'd add this note

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try `if (c == ' ')`

- `"` means `string`.
- `'` means `char`.
- `=` means assignment.
- `==` means equality.